# How to have a set number of attempts for user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to user to have 3 incorrect guesses before the program closes but I cant get the "Incorrect try again" messages to go one by one after each wrong response.

```
while True:
    password = input("Enter the password (3 guesses left):")
    x = 1


    if password == "Cookie":
        print("You guessed the password right")
        quit()

    if password != "Cookie" and x == 1:
        x = x + 1
        print("Incorrect try again (2 guesses left)")

    if password != "Cookie" and x == 2:
        x = x + 1
        print("Incorrect try again (1 guess left)")

    if password != "Cookie" and x == 3:
        x = x + 1
        print("You ran out of guesses")
        quit()
```

Comment: `x=3; while x>0; guess = input(f'Enter password ({x} guesses remaining)'); if guess == "Cookie": print("correct."); quit(); x -= 1; print('Incorrect.");`

Answer (score 1):

Because you used if instead of elif
In general, the structure of using conditions is such that when your conditions are related, you should use if, elif, else. It is not related, again, it is done because x is increased, and that is why you are having problems. Your correct code is as below

```
x = 1
while True:
    password = input("Enter the password (3 guesses left):")
    if password == "Cookie":
        print("You guessed the password right")
        quit()

    if password != "Cookie" and x == 1:
        x = x + 1
        print("Incorrect try again (2 guesses left)")

    elif password != "Cookie" and x == 2:
        x = x + 1
        print("Incorrect try again (1 guess left)")

    elif password != "Cookie" and x == 3:
        x = x + 1
        print("You ran out of guesses")
        quit()
```

And of course x must be outside of while

Comment: No need to check the password every time. It's wrong... because the first IF didn't trigger.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I just wanted to show the problem of the code and tell the solution for this code, but logically what you say is more correct and better.